# how to implement Socket.io on Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, websocket, socket.io, tomcat7

We have existing applications which are hosted on tomcat 6 and we are moving to tomcat 7 which  provides websockets support.

I wanted to try socket.io in our application, for some of the features based on websockets, since it has very good cross browser support.

I couldn't find any resources online for this combination, socket.io + tomcat,though there are  quite a few for ([Socket.io + jetty)](https://github.com/Ovea/Socket.IO-Java).

Has anyone tried it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though I haven't used, I recommend the Atmosphere project to develop socket.io application on the JVM. Their support is built on top of Atmosphere API which is powered by Servlet 3 spec and all most server-specific features. That means, you don't need to stick Tomcat 7 to use socketio on the JVM.

http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2012/06/04/writing-socket-io-application-that-runs-on-the-jvm/