# Can i use Socket.io with Spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, socket.io

I am gonna develop a real time game for andriod/ios and i need a server which transmit data with client real time.
Can i use socket.io with Spring boot?
Or if the answer is no , using websockets with Spring boot is the solution?

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568700/best-java-server-implementation-for-socket-io but not flagging as duplicate as this specifically mentions Spring boot

Answer (score 18):

The original [Socket.IO](https://socket.io) server is designed to be used in Javascript, mostly Node.

Yet, there are other implementations of the Socket.IO server for other languages.

For Java, there is the [Netty-socketio](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio) project, an open-source Java implementation of the Socket.IO server, based on the [Netty](https://netty.io) Java server framework (the Netty-socketio project is also suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16711894/2938364)).

[This example Spring Boot application](https://github.com/jamesjieye/netty-socketio.spring) uses Netty-socketio to provide a Socket.IO server within a Spring Boot application.

So **yes**, you can use (an open-source Java implementation of) Socket.IO together with Spring Boot.